# OneHotEncoding Categorical data

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to use OneHotEncoding to transform the second column of my csv file, which consists of company names.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [1])]), remainder='passthrough'
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))
```

and I received this error:

```
    ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [1])]), remainder='passthrough'
                  ^
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Where did i go wrong? I understand that perhaps there is an error with how I wrote the ct line, but i do not know exactly what I did wrong.

Comment: isn't because you have ) after ] ? which remainder must be inside the ColumnTransformer function ?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you set a bracket incorrectly and it should probably be like this:

```
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [1])], remainder='passthrough')
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Upon running the corrected code, i received this error message:ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'FLANG Group' Flang group is one of the company names i am trying to OneHotEncode (the first one one in the dataset). Does this error mean I cannot have spaces between company names? or it means something different?

Comment: Can you open up a new question with a minimal reproducible example of your code (so also with some data that can be used with it) to reproduce that error? Currently like this its hard to tell where the error is coming from for me.

Comment: I have opened up a new question, did you see it? It's titled 'ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'Flang Group'

Answer (score 0):

you can call columntransformer from sklearn.compose first
write the code like this
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [1])]), remainder='passthrough'
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))